# What is the (initial) root password for Ubuntu on Nexus 7?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Is it possible to install anything on nexus 7' Ubuntu? I installed Ubuntu, booted, but there's only default admin account.

Answer (score 7):

It's `ubuntu`

You can find more info here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/UsingTheDevice

For more information about this, check out:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/

Comment: Ubuntu offers Sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [wiki link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/UsingTheDevice) bjaanes sent you:

*sudo password*

*The default sudo password is **ubuntu**.*

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tested this, but as a rule of thumb Ubuntu never lets you log in as root. To "become" root, run "sudo su" in a terminal and enter your user's password -- I assume it let you configure this? If not, then I really don't know. I would like to test Ubuntu for Nexus 7 at some point.